# How do I make a cross-correlation matrix for panel data in R?

Tags: r, correlation

So, based on R documentation, below is a sample code of how to create a correlation matrix for panel data. I am sure what the grp variable with "rep" does, and how to apply it to my own dataset. Hence, I am unable to proceed the following line. Also, why do I have to specify a certain column in cortab, "pGrunfeld$value" below?

`````
pGrunfeld <- pdata.frame(Grunfeld)
grp <- c(rep(1, 100), rep(2, 50), rep(3, 50)) # make 3 groups
cortab(pGrunfeld$value, grouping = grp, groupnames = c("A", "B", "C"))````
`````